# JSON Schema - Enum of Objects

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

I'm new to JSON schema. My goal is to have a JSON property that is an object. It's keys relate to each other, meaning multiple keys always have the same values together. This will probably help make it clear, it's my attempt to do this with an enum:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "title": "Part",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "relationship": {
      "type": "object",
      "enum": [
        {
          "code": "1",
          "value": "MEMBER"
        },
        {
          "code": "2",
          "value": "SPOUSE"
        },
        {
          "code": "3",
          "value": "CHILD"
        },
        {
          "code": "4",
          "value": "STUDENT"
        },
        {
          "code": "5",
          "value": "DISABILITY_DEPENDENT"
        },
        {
          "code": "6",
          "value": "ADULT_DEPENDENT"
        },
        {
          "code": "8",
          "value": "DOMESTIC_PARTNER"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So using an enum like this works, even though I can't find it anywhere in the JSON Schema spec. However, the error message sucks. Normally I get the most extremely detailed error messages from schema validation, however in this case I do not.

```
$.part.relationship: does not have a value in the enumeration [, , , , , , ]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using a Java parser for JSON Schema:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.53</version>
</dependency>
```

Not sure if the error message is the fault of the parser or something I'm doing bad with the schema.

Comment: Do you have control over the JSON instance structure, or are you receiving it from a 3rd party and just want to validate it?

Comment: It's complicated. There are multiple variations of the structure, and so the idea is based on the tenant select the appropriate schemas and validate against each one for each sub-set of fields.

Comment: I would honestly stop trying to have both the string and the number in the enum and just enforce one or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was news to me, but [according to the spec](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html) it does seem that objects are valid enum values. That said, your usage is quite unusual. I've not seen it used before.

> the six primitive types ("null", "boolean", "object", "array", "number", or "string")
> ...
>
> **6.1.2. enum**
> ...
>
> Elements in the array might be of **any type**, including null.

Your problem is fundamentally that the library that you're using doesn't know how to convert those objects to printable strings. Even if it did give it a reasonable go, you might end up with

```
does not have a value in the enumeration [{"code": "1", "value":"MEMBER"}, {"code": "2" ...
```

which might be okay, but it's hardly amazing. If the code and value were both valid but didn't match, you might have to look quite closely at the list before you ever saw the problem.

JSON Schema in general is not very good at enforcing constraints between what it considers to be 2 unrelated fields. That's beyond the scope of it what it aims to do. It's trying to validate the structure. Dependencies between fields are business constraints, not structural ones.

I think the best thing you could do to achieve readable error messages would be to have 2 sub-properties, each with an enumeration containing 8 values; one for the codes, one for the values.

Then you'll get

```
$.part.relationship.code does not have a value in the enumeration [1,2,3,4 ...
```

or

```
$.part.relationship.value does not have a value in the enumeration ["MEMBER", "SPOUSE", ...
```

You can do some additional business validation on top of the schema validation if enforcing that constraint is important to you. Then generate your own error such as

```
code "1" does not match value "SPOUSE"
```

Comment: As much as I wish i could fix the underlying error message, this is probably the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're actually looking for is the "anyOf" keyword, where you can create a union of constant objects for a property.

Something like this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "title": "Part",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "relationship": {
      "type": "object",
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "code": { "const": "1" },
            "value": { "const": "MEMBER" }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "code": { "const": "2" },
            "value": { "const": "SPOUSE" }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "code": { "const": "3" },
            "value": { "const": "CHILD" }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "code": { "const": "4" },
            "value": { "const": "STUDENT" }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "code": { "const": "5" },
            "value": { "const": "DISABILITY_DEPENDENT" }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "code": { "const": "6" },
            "value": { "const": "ADULT_DEPENDENT" }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "code": { "const": "8" },
            "value": { "const": "DOMESTIC_PARTNER" }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": ["relationship"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `code` and `value` always have the same values relative to each other, why encode both in the JSON?  Just encode a single value in the JSON and infer the other in the application.

This will be much easier to validate.

Comment: The goal is to use JSON Schema to do all the validation rather than convert into POJOs. That is why I want the schema to validate the values relative to each other.

Comment: Do what you want, but my point is that encoding both values goes against established architectural practices. By encoding one, you don't HAVE to validate that they match because you _infer_ the other, meaning that you assume the value you get is correct, and you know what the map is, so you can easily get the other value.  It means that you don't validate two values; you only validate one: either the string is in a predefined set, or the number is within a specified range.

Comment: Agree. But sometimes you might be consuming data from a service whose schema you either don't control or maybe doesn't even exist. In that case, you still might want to use a schema (in the latter case, reverse engineered) to perform your validation. Normalisation should be the first thing you try, but if it's not possible then OP's example still has use-cases

Comment: In that case, determine with the client (or just decide) which you want to use as source of truth.  In my experience, relying on data to be right like this causes problems.  Otherwise, you'll need to just have the schema as you have it, and work within the limitations of the library to configure the error messaging.